# Macro Webservice Libre Office - called multiple times

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I am calling a webservice from a Libre Office macro. I use it to pass data from Calc to a webserver, but the macro calls the webservice 5 times, even though, the command is only called once:

```
svc = createUnoService("com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess")
dim ss as string
ss = getWSAdress() + "webservices/" + t
sendWS=svc.callFunction("WEBSERVICE",Array(ss))
```

Can I avoid the webservice being called 5 times?

Comment: I don't believe the one code line will calling the webservice 5 times. I believe, the Macro itself will be called 5 times. So how are you calling the Macro code? Is it a `Sub` or a `Function`? And how exactly are you calling it? As a `UDF` via formula in a cell? Via a button click? Via event listener?

Comment: It is a Sub which I call manually. I noticed because I am sending data which was written into the database multiple times. I further made sure, the function is only called once by using breakpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested. `WEBSERVICE` makes the following HTTP 1.1 requests on each call:

```
PROPFIND /test HTTP/1.1
Keep-Alive: 
Connection: TE, Keep-Alive
TE: trailers
Host: 192.168.0.10:2000
Depth: 0
Content-Length: 237
Content-Type: application/xml
Pragma: no-cache
User-Agent: LibreOffice
Post-Data:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<propfind xmlns="DAV:"><prop>
<resourcetype xmlns="DAV:"/>
<IsReadOnly xmlns="http://ucb.openoffice.org/dav/props/"/>
<getcontenttype xmlns="DAV:"/>
<supportedlock xmlns="DAV:"/>
</prop></propfind>

PROPFIND /test HTTP/1.1
Connection: TE
TE: trailers
Host: 192.168.0.10:2000
Depth: 0
Content-Length: 237
Content-Type: application/xml
Pragma: no-cache
User-Agent: LibreOffice
Post-Data:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<propfind xmlns="DAV:"><prop>
<resourcetype xmlns="DAV:"/>
<IsReadOnly xmlns="http://ucb.openoffice.org/dav/props/"/>
<getcontenttype xmlns="DAV:"/>
<supportedlock xmlns="DAV:"/>
</prop></propfind>

PROPFIND /test HTTP/1.1
Connection: TE
TE: trailers
Host: 192.168.0.10:2000
Depth: 0
Content-Length: 237
Content-Type: application/xml
Pragma: no-cache
User-Agent: LibreOffice
Post-Data:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<propfind xmlns="DAV:"><prop>
<resourcetype xmlns="DAV:"/>
<IsReadOnly xmlns="http://ucb.openoffice.org/dav/props/"/>
<getcontenttype xmlns="DAV:"/>
<supportedlock xmlns="DAV:"/>
</prop></propfind>

HEAD /test HTTP/1.1
Connection: TE
TE: trailers
Host: 192.168.0.10:2000
Pragma: no-cache
User-Agent: LibreOffice

GET /test HTTP/1.1
Connection: TE
TE: trailers
Host: 192.168.0.10:2000
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Pragma: no-cache
User-Agent: LibreOffice
```

So you are right. There are 5 requests each call. The PROPFIND requests comes from HTTP [WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) extension.

So either your web service must support WebDAV or it must only react on the GET request.

Comment: Is there a simple PHP based way to test for the GET request?

Comment: Just found it: $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "GET"